# How to add images in Tab Bar compatible for iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+?

Tags: storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6, uitabbar

I have to create an app with four tabs and I need to add images on tabs also?
how it can be done in XCode 6 so that images don't look blurred when app will run on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+.